# Show English characters and simple special characters only

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, regex

Problem I need to fix is that if I enter characters outside English range in description textarea it shows that only 1 character is used for 1 character typed, so you can write full text area of 2000 characters.

**head.php**

script shows all (ā, ē, ī, ū, ') characters as 1 symbol typed. But in real the code understands those characters as many ascii characters. So when I try to submit full form with these characters (āēīū', and others) in submit.php IF statement error "*Description should be between 500 and 2000 characters long!*" shows up.

So it's because for example this special symbol ' is treated inserting this character \ before '. So it turns showing wrong count.
I would like to enter only english characters. But with some special characters.

For example ' this character is needed. But I need that it counts as 1 character not like 2 because of this \ slash for security reason.

head.php

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var text_max = 2000;
        $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_max + ' characters');

        $('#textarea').keyup(function() {
        var text_length = $('#textarea').val().length;
        var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

        $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters');
        });
      });
    </script>
```

function.php

```
    function sanitize($data) {
      return htmlentities(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($data)));
    }
```

display.php

```
    <?php

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` ");

      while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

        $description = $row2['description'];

     <?php if(strlen($description) >= 1000) { echo $description = substr($description, 0, 1000). '...'; ?>
      <a href="description.php?page=<?php echo $uid;?>">Read more</a>
    <?php } else { echo $description; } ?>
      }
    ?>
```

submit.php

```
    <?php $description = sanitize($_POST['description']); 

      $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `table` (description)
        VALUES ('$description')";
    ?>

    <form action="submit.php" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
      <span id="insert">Description</span><div id="textarea_feedback"></div><br>
      <textarea maxlength="2000" id="textarea" name="description" ><?php echo stripslashes($description); ?></textarea><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
   </form>

    <?php
      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if (!$con){
            exit("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("database",$con);

      if ((strlen($description) < 500) or (strlen($description) > 2000)) {
      echo "<h1 class='top'>Description should be between 500 and 2000 characters long!</h1>";
      } else
            {
      mysql_query($sql2,$con);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If your intent is to count characters in a string, what about [this approach](http://ideone.com/oFcISq)? Match all Unicode letters first, remove them, and then count the rest and then sum the values up?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the mb_strlen, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php, with your encoding you will get the correct length of the string.

Example:

```
echo mb_strlen('āēīū', 'UTF8');
```

Output:

> 4

Demo:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8c92e97df6d10b09b062c27c2d17a58a7efd23a3

You should use this before escaping.

Note without the encoding it still counts each byte as an individual character.

```
echo mb_strlen('āēīū');
```

Output:

> 8

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use utf8 throughout -- encoding in client, `CHARACTER SET` in table, and `<meta>` tag in html, things will be all good.

āēīū is 4 *characters* according to MySQL, but occupies 8 *bytes*.

Do not use the `mysql_*`, switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.  `mysql_*` is deprecated and going away soon.  (And it has issues.)

Do not store escapes in the database; they are useful only when handing strings from one thing to another (form, php, mysql, html, etc).